# javascript phonebook project refreshes page after adding a new record

Tags: javascript, html

I have this vanilla js project which is supposed to be a phonebook with add, remove, and search functionalities.

Problem is when I try to add a new record, the record disappears right after showing up. I assume the page refreshes but I don't know why.

This is the phonebook function:

```
function PhoneBook() {
  this.records = [];

  this.add = function (name, phone) {
    const contact = new PhoneBookRecord(name, phone);
    this.records.push(contact);

    // this.records.forEach(function (item) {
      
    // })

    
    console.log(this.records);
    return this;
  };

  this.search = function (name) {
    const result = this.records.includes(name);
  };

  this.remove = function () {

  };
  
}
```

When a user clicks on the add button on page, the element's onClick event is called and inside that `phonebook.add()` is called with the name and phone the user has entered.

Link to code on github:
https://github.com/newshahn/vanillajsphonebook

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Please take a look at our [tour]. A [mre] would be a lot more usefull then a github link.

Comment: @0stone0 noted. I'll try to add a part of the code right now.

Comment: There's no action prop on the `<form>`, so the page will always rerender to '/?'

Comment: @0stone0 um sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. not having an action prop in form results in the page to refresh every time user clicks on the button? Am I supposed to add a redirection link for every time user clicks on button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the form is submitting when the button is pressed, you need to call e.preventDefault() from the on button click event handlers or it will submit the page.  the `onclick = function() {}`  can take the argument
`onclick = function(e) { ...  e.preventDefault() }`

With all due respect, id recommend putting the page elements into the html and not building the entire page through dom manipulation in js.  its was not easy to see what was going on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You're totally right. It's not best practice to add HTML elements using js but this is actually a homework assignment and we were given this template like the way it is now. Thanks again.